# Conditional Formatting of decimal places

Tags: formatting

I have a spread sheet set to format numbers with 4 decimal places and in the legend it states 4.  I want to be able to change the number in the legend box to say 5 and then the formatting in all the cells change to have 5 decimal places.  If I change it to 3, the cells reformat to having 3 decimal places and so forth.  Is this possible?

Comment: What “spread sheet” program? Excel?

Comment: Yes it is in an excel spreadsheet